# What is the general approach to oridinal product of $(\omega^2 + \omega...) \cdot \omega$?

Tags: ordinals

If we have some kind of ordinal in Cantor normal form, and there are at least two non-trivial parts of it, what is the general approach to calculating it? Only way I heard of is building an explicit isomorphic function, but this is getting quite complex once you take something more sophisticated than $(\omega + k) \cdot \omega$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\alpha (\beta+\gamma) = \alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma$ (though it's not distributive in the other direction), so your case of $(\omega^2 + \omega) \omega$ is structurally as complicated as it gets.

We define $$(\omega^2 + \omega) \omega = \sup \{ (\omega^2 + \omega) n : n < \omega\}$$
But $$(\omega^2 + \omega)(n+1) = (\omega^2 + \omega)n + (\omega^2 + \omega)$$
and $$(\omega^2+\omega)0 = 0$$
so inductively $$(\omega^2+\omega)n = \omega^2n + \omega$$
whence $$(\omega^2+\omega) \omega = \sup_{n < \omega} (\omega^2n + \omega) = \omega^3$$

This same technique works pretty much always, though perhaps it gets a bit more complicated to apply. You might like to prove several generalisations.

Comment: And what if we have something like $\omega^2$ on the right?

Comment: You meant $n \omega^2+\omega+(\omega^2+\omega) = (n+1)\omega^2+\omega$ so by induction $(\omega^2+\omega)n = \omega^2 n + \omega$. Whence $(\omega^2+\omega) \omega =  \sup_{n < \omega} (\omega^2  + \omega )n = \sup_{n < \omega} \omega^2 n + \omega = \omega^3 $ the last step by the least upper bound

Comment: I meant if we have $(\omega^2 + 2) \cdot \omega^2$.